# Has Marvel ever referenced the song "Catch Me Now I'm Falling?"

Tags: marvel, captain-america, music, reference, rock-music

"Catch Me Now I'm Falling," by the Kinks is written from the perspective of Captain America.

> I remember, when you were down
>
> And you needed a helping hand
>
> I came to feed you
>
> But now that I need you
>
> You won't give me a second glance
>
> Now I'm calling all citizens from all over the world
>
> This is Captain America calling

Have any Marvel works ever referenced this song?